# How can I automatically register 'controllers as services' in other directories in Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony5

### Background

I want to use [functional cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) to organise my controllers.

This means that I will not have a `Controllers/` directory, which makes it easy for the framework, but I will organise my code by use-case. An arbitrary example:

- `src/FetchLatestNews/Controller.php`
- `src/FetchLatestNews/News.php`
- `src/FetchLatestNews/NewsRepository.php`
- ...etc

However, Symfony is set up by default to require all controllers in one place. See `services.yaml`:

```yaml
    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Following the above template, I *could* just place the new `src/FetchLatestNews/Controller` in there and then add each new controller each time. However, **I don't want to, nor should I have to, manually update this file every time I create a new use-case**.

### Question

How can I avoid this error:

> maybe you forgot to register the controller as a service or missed tagging it with the "controller.service_arguments"

As a user I should not have to care about manually adding `service_arguments` or any other configuration. When I specify a route, the thing it's pointing to is therefore a controller.

The ideal workflow would be:

- Create a controller wherever I like.
- Add a route to `routes.yaml` referencing the controller.
- That's it!

Is it possible to achieve this workflow in Symfony? It should be, because anything from a route --> some class will be a controller. Is there a way to use a regex, or some other solution?

*Note*: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51910803/736809) suggests an empty interface sort of 'hack'. This is not ideal, either. Any alternatives?

Comment: *Note: I've tagged both [tag:symfony4] and [tag:symfony5] here because I don't believe the API has changed significantly between the versions.*

Comment: Do your controllers extend from AbstractController?  If so they will work just fine regardless of where they are located as long as autoconfigure is on.  The controller comment in services.yaml is not as clear as it should be.

Comment: No, they will never extend `AbstractController` as that would couple me to the framework.

Comment: Okay.  You also linked to my "hacked" answer.  I don't consider it to be a hack.  Symfony has the ability to tag classes based on which interfaces they implement.  This capability is used all over the place in the framework.  Here is a [repo](https://github.com/cerad/zayso4) that basically follows the same pattern as you are proposing.

Comment: I mean, it's one way of doing it, but for me an empty interface would be something that only exists for the framework to work with - something I'm trying to avoid. The framework should have all the information it needs to initialise the controller with auto-DI. I'll take a look at the repo though and appreciate the response.

Comment: I understand the desire for "framework independence" and if you do come up with an alternative approach then by all means make a demo repo and share the link.  I have never looked in detail at what point in the build process the routes are available.  But you might be able to come up with something.  On the other hand, to me framework independence mostly means keeping your controller actions as thin as practical.

Comment: I would assume you would have to build a CompilerPass that adds the tag to your controllers. however, for that to work, they have to somewhere be registered as services, which probably can be done by just assuming everything in src (except exceptions ^^) to be a service. here is how the tag is realized in symfony: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/RegisterControllerArgumentLocatorsPass.php ("ArgumentLocatorsPass")

Comment: @Jakumi Exactly. That which Symfony defines as a 'service' is in fact just something that is auto-injectable, and in effect everything in `src/` should be injectable at any time so this looks promising.

Comment: tbh, I wonder if turning on autowiring will already work ....... https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#an-autowiring-example

Comment: @Jakumi This is a fresh checkout of Symfony 5 latest which already has `"autowire:  true"` set by default, unfortunately.

Comment: that makes me sad ;o/

Comment: you could also just use `resource: '../src/*/Controller.php'`

Comment: @Rufinus If this also works, and I'll give it a shot - thanks! Feel free to either add an answer and I'll change the correctly marked one. However, *does this work with subdirectories*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Please note, this answer has been updated again with new information*.

The `controller.service_arguments` tag is only required to allow action injection. Stick with constructor injection and `__invoke()` and that's all you need.

The public addition below was a requirement, but it turns out you don't need a compiler pass for this and it can be all done at the services.yaml level. Therefore the only thing you need is the following:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true         // <---- This is the new additional config.
```

Then, any class can be used in `routes.yaml` as a controller and construct injection works just fine.

> *Note: The original answer is below. Thanks to Jakumi for pointing me in the right direction.*

You need to add a compiler pass to do two things. On booting and registering things for automatic dependency injection, if a class has `Controller` in the name:

- Add the tag `controller.service_arguments`, which is the tag you'd normally need to add yourself manually in `services.yaml` to allow setter injection (you can ignore this if you don't care about setter injection)
- Set the class to public, because Symfony had this weird idea that the concept of public or private anything is not to be inferred from the class access modifier (seriously?) - *This is the important thing as Symfony will complain that the controller is private otherwise*

*Don't forget you don't have to use the logic for "Controller in name". It can be "Controller" is at the end of the class name which is probably better.*

Anyway, first create a `CompilerPass`. Put it anywhere you want. I put mine next to `Kernel.php`.

```php
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\{Compiler\CompilerPassInterface, ContainerBuilder};

class ControllersAsServices implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        foreach ($container->getDefinitions() as $definition) {
            if (strpos($definition->getClass(), "Controller") === false) {
                continue;
            }

            $definition->addTag("controller.service_arguments");
            $definition->setPublic(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `Kernel.php`, you need to tell it to use this new one. Override the protected function `build` and add your compiler passes as the documentation shows:

```php
protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $container->addCompilerPass(new ControllersAsServices, PassConfig::TYPE_BEFORE_OPTIMIZATION, -1);

    parent::build($container);
}
```

**Clear your dev cache**. Nothing changed for me until I did this.

Now, any class with `Controller` in the name can be autowired as it should have been originally.

Original anser from Jakumi below:

---

I believe the best approach in your case would be to implement a CompilerPass, to add classes to the container:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html#adding-classes-to-compile

in the process there's probably a way to also add the tags.

Symfony caters to the controller.service_arguments tag via the [RegisterControllerArgumentLocatorsPass](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/RegisterControllerArgumentLocatorsPass.php), which resolves the constructor arguments and checks for some traits. If you get your compiler pass' priority higher, you could probably solve this problem easily then ...

Comment: some may argue this as a "link only answer" and they'll be expecting code, so if you leave it up you risk downvotes but when I write the compiler pass successfully I'll update your answer with the simplest code example to make it work :thumbs-up:

Comment: why o why would you do something like this? just set a interface you can give your controller classes and use this to inject in the compiler pass. this needless looping ... *facepalm*

Comment: @Rufinus Using an empty interface or 'marker interface' is a well known anti-pattern. *An interface should define a polymorphic behaviour*. A marker interface can be replaced by an annotation or, in this case, a YAML configuration which I am trying to avoid and for good reason. Your facepalm is for that misunderstanding.

Comment: @Jimbo nicely done. did not expect the requirement for setting it public though.

Comment: @Jakumi In fact, the `controller.service_arguments` tag is only needed to enable setter injection. The public is the thing that is definitely needed because controller "services" by default are for some reason private. Otherwise using any class as a controller works automatically in Symfony. I basically figured out how to add the public requirement automatically.

Comment: Nah, we got there together in the end. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Jimbo I just can't help but wonder why you would use the Symfony ecosystem when it utilizes what you consider to be an anti-pattern?  What is the difference between tagging based on an interface as opposed to class suffix?  Just seems like you making things harder and more fragile.

Comment: @Cerad You think that using Symfony precludes accepting that a few poor design decisions exist, such as annotations polluting the domain model? There are a lot of other positives to take from it. It's still a *hell* of a lot better than other frameworks like Laravel for best practices. Tagging based on an *empty* interface is something there that exists for the framework's sake and is nothing to do with the code being written. The code should not have to change just so that it can work with a framework. This is why Symfony is good - I configured the framework in a documented way.

Comment: @jimbo - you really want to tell me to inject stuff based on a class name is BETTER and less a anti-pattern than to use a interface? and nobody said the interface has to be empty btw.

Comment: @Rufinus The interfaces *are* empty, and there's plenty of these flying around in Symfony lately. Abstractions for the sake of abstractions is also poor practice. Don't even create an interface until you need one. It's becoming a common pattern in Symfony to use empty 'marker' interfaces and that's not good. Here it depends - you can either place everything in one directory `Controllers/` and accept the tradeoff that your software architecture groups all controllers together and lacks context, you can wire everything manually, or you can base it on a common convention.

Comment: Before I was basing it on two things: 1 "Controller" at the end and containing one single `__invoke()` function. That'd be difficult to mess up and even if it did, it just means a class would have an additional tag. It's not even a big issue. Regardless, I just updated the answer as `public: true` can be used, so you don't even need a compiler pass unless you want to add additional tags. Thanks all!

Comment: I would argue that public: true is not necessarily a good default though ... but this is starting to get out of scope

Comment: @Jakumi From my understanding, `public: true` only allows `$this->get()` (service locator, another anti-pattern), which opposes dependency injection. But this only enables that option, it doesn't mean you use it.

Comment: @Jimbo I must say ... I'm impressed how you expanded on my answer. I feel slightly bad, since more praise should come to you ;o/

Comment: @Jakumi This was years ago but you led me to understanding the right answer. The praise goes to you also :)